# How to get External and Internal storage directory path

Tags: huawei-developers, harmonyos

I need to get External and Internal storage directory path to find it's size and I am not able to get the path. In android we have

```
android.os.Enviroment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From official documents of HarmonyOS - [Internal storage](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/context-0000001054440065#ZH-CN_TOPIC_0000001054440065__getFilesDir--) and [External storage](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/context-0000001054440065#ZH-CN_TOPIC_0000001054440065__getExternalFilesDir-java_lang_String-)

You can create a utils class in your project and use the following functions to get the internal and external storage paths:

```
/**
 * Returns the absolute path to the directory of the device's internal storage
 *
 * @param context
 * @return
 */
public static File getInternalStorage(Context context) {
    return context.getFilesDir(); //Can be called directly too
}


/**
 * Returns the absolute path to the directory of the device's primary shared/external storage
 *
 * @param context
 * @return
 */
public static File getExternalStorage(Context context) {
    File externalFilesDirPath = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    String externalStoragePath = "";
    int subPathIndex = externalFilesDirPath.getAbsolutePath().indexOf("/emulated/0/");
    if (subPathIndex > 0) {
        subPathIndex += "/emulated/0/".length();
    }
    if (subPathIndex >= 0 && externalFilesDirPath.getAbsolutePath().contains("/storage/")) {
        externalStoragePath = externalFilesDirPath.getAbsolutePath().substring(0, subPathIndex);
    }
    if (externalStoragePath.length() > 0) {
        externalFilesDirPath = new File(externalStoragePath);
    }
    return externalFilesDirPath;
}
```

Once you obtain [File](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/file-0000001054119759) object, you can call the following functions to get the storage information -

- `getTotalSpace()`: Returns the size of the partition named by this
  abstract pathname.
- `getUsableSpace​()`: Returns the number of bytes available to this virtual machine on the partition named by this abstract pathname.
- `getFreeSpace()`: Returns the number of unallocated bytes in the partition named by this abstract pathname.